setting up a sandbox for minecraft for grandchildren
I have an Dell r610 running ubuntu 24.04 server, plus two pc running windows 10, two running windows 11, and a ten year old Imac. I'm using the ISP router and have a couple of 1gig dumb switches.
I can ping everything on the network, from everything on the network.
I have after much effort, been able to get samba to work (I think) I can see and move files between all clients.
I'm currently a WORKGROUP.
I want to setup a sandbox a with Minecraft server so that my grandchildren and their friends can play in a safe place, free from both predator's and constant marketing. So I'm looking for suggestions or best practices.
Many thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What have you tried? There are online guides, e.g., https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058525452-How-to-Setup-a-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Server, https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/tech-takes/how-to-make-minecraft-server

As @DrMoishePippik has said, there are some really good guides online. You can also add a whitelist so that only certain people have access as well
